# Mock/Simulate ADFS for Dev Environment on Linux (or where windows server is not available)

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0

I am working on a Project to connect Django to [ADSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services). Based on Online Documentation it seems ADSF is a Windows Server ONLY feature.

- Can ASDF be installed on Linux Environment?
- IF connection to Windows Server is not available in Dev Environment, is it possible to get some kind of mock server or simulator to test out code (connecting app to ADFS) during Development Stage/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Windows Server only.

No - won't run on Linux.

You could have a look at [EmbeddedSTS](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/wiki/EmbeddedSts) as long as you are happy using WS Fed.

Comment: Ok i'll have a look at it